# Angular how to update library metadata.json file

Tags: javascript, angular

Recently I've installed a local library from my company. I wanted to add some extra features in that library for my app, so I changed some components. I copied the modules and components to my src folder to use it without an npm install. 
So now I this is my folder structure:

Local libraries

-filter.component.d.ts

-filter.component.js

-filter.component.js.map

-filter.component.metadata.json

-filter.component.ngfactory.js.map

-filter.component.module.d.ts

-filter.component.module.js

-filter.component.module.js.map

-filter.component.module.metadata.json

-filter.component.module.ngfactory.js.map

For example, I changed the filter.component.js file. This works locally. But now I have to deploy my application. Is there a possibility to update these files automatically? I've searched but did not find much information on how to update libraries. I came across NGC, but I can't seem to work it out in my application build process. Any suggestions on how to do this?